# When to retrieve data from API again? (Token)

Tags: react-native, rest

*Working on a very basic React-Native App with a login-form, fetching Data from an API and display it. (Token based OAuth2 with Password Grant Type)*

**Question:** When is the best time to retrieve data from my REST service again?

Currently I only fetch the data once, and that is when the user logs in.

**Possible Solution:** My idea would be to save the user data (username,password | token) in AsyncStorage (or SecureStorage) and to query it again every x minutes - Is that the normal workflow or do I have a major security gap?

*I did not include any code, because it is a question of understanding and I shouldn't have any problems with the programming part.*

Comment: That depends entirely on the nature of the data. How frequently the data changes, how bad it'd be to have outdated info displayed temporarily, etc.

Comment: it´s important to keep the data updated - but is it common to call the API every time the user switches Tab oder to call every minute?

Comment: Again, that depends on the data involved. Will your users care if you cache data for a minute? An hour? A day? A week?

Comment: The App will be used to only display data which can be/will be changed from a third party company (I call their API)

Comment: I give up. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing user password is a big NO.

If your server is using standard OAuth2, normally the sign in response would include an access token and a refresh token. See [the standard doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5).

The access token is embedded in the app's requests to the resource server in the session.

The refresh token is used to retrieve a new access token, either when the current access token has expired, or when a new session is started. So this refresh token is what the app should save, across sessions.

The refresh token's lifespan should be reasonably long such that the client, in this case your app, doesn't have to worry about redoing user sign in.